# pandas index rename has no effect

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which `frame.index.name == 'aaa'`. I try to rename the index by

```
frame.rename(index={'aaa': 'bbb'})
```

but after I execute it, the index name does not change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `inplace` as in: `frame.rename(index={'aaa': 'bbb'}, inplace=True)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang: still no effect

Comment: try df.index=df.index.str.strip(), then rename

Comment: `rename` renames the `index`, not the `index.name`.

Comment: @DavidZemens: can you clarify? I thought `index.name` was just the name of the index object

Comment: `index.name` is the name of the index. but `frame.rename` will rename the *labels* within that axis, not the axis itself. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) which renames the *axis labels*, not the *axis* itself.

What you need is [`Index.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.rename.html#pandas.Index.rename), which you can use to:

> Alter Index or MultiIndex name
>
> Able to set new names without level. Defaults to returning new index. Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.

Or possibly: [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis) to:

> Set the name of the axis for the index or columns

Or, you could just assign directly to the `frame.index.name='bbb'`